# Passing data to custom view

Tags: android, android-view

I want to pass data to my custom view, a list. It worked but for some reasons I get now a Nullpointer exception and I have no idea why.

I pass the data through the constructor but the list size is always zero but when I try to get the size of the list IN the constructor I get the right size but outside of it always 0.

MainActivity.java

```
LineChart2 lineChart2;
List<items> items = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    items.add(new items(R.color.babyBlau,10,"Internet"));
    items.add(new items(R.color.colorAccent,20,"Internet"));
    items.add(new items(R.color.rot,60,"Internet"));

    lineChart2 = new LineChart2(MainActivity.this,items);


}
```

LineChart2.java
    package com.example.viewtest;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LineChart2 extends View {

List<items> items = new ArrayList<>();
Paint paintThinBlackLine;
Paint paintThinGrayLines;
Paint paintText;
float padding = 50;
float padding_left = padding * 3;
float padding_text = padding_left/2;

public LineChart2(Context context, List<com.example.viewtest.items> items) {
    super(context);
    this.items = items;
    initPaints();
}

public LineChart2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initPaints();
}

public LineChart2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initPaints();
}

public LineChart2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initPaints();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width,width/2);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // thin lines
    for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        float paddingbetween = (getHeight()-padding-padding)/6;
        canvas.drawLine(padding_left,paddingbetween*i,getWidth()-padding,paddingbetween*i,paintThinGrayLines);
        Log.d("HALLO",""+items.size());
            //canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(items.get(i).value),padding_text,paddingbetween*i,paintText);

    }
}

public void initPaints(){
    paintThinBlackLine = new Paint();
    paintThinBlackLine.setColor(Color.parseColor("#6FB4B3B3"));
    paintThinBlackLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintThinBlackLine.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paintThinBlackLine.setStrokeWidth(3);

    paintThinGrayLines = new Paint();
    paintThinGrayLines.setColor(Color.parseColor("#6FB4B3B3"));
    paintThinGrayLines.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintThinGrayLines.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paintThinGrayLines.setStrokeWidth(2);

    paintText = new Paint();
    paintText.setTextSize(20);
    paintText.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF696969"));
    paintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

}
```

}

Comment: Are you doing something else with "items" in "MainActivity"? Also are you sure it is the same LineChart2 object in and out of the constructor?

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE?

Comment: No just what I posted.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai NPE?

Comment: Can you add the code that you get the size with outside the constructor ?

Comment: @mohnage7 it is already in the onDraw method "        Log.d("HALLO",""+items.size());
"

Comment: Null Pointer Exception. Where is the null pointer happening?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Here:         Log.d("HALLO",""+items.size());

Comment: @JonnyDough how do you attach your custom view to it's container layout?

Comment: @mohnage7 in the activityMain xml file    <com.example.viewtest.LineChart2
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Comment: @JonnyDough that's the issue. in this situation onDraw will be invoked without having your data. please check my answer below.

Comment: @mohnage7 but it worked before. It makes no sense for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have compiled your code and it works well. the only reason that will generate the issue is attaching the layout to it's container before settings the data.

It's better to add your layout from the code like below.

```
    LinearLayout anyDesiredLayout= findViewById(R.id.layout);

    items.add(new items(R.color.colorAccent, 10, "Internet"));
    items.add(new items(R.color.colorAccent, 20, "Internet"));
    items.add(new items(R.color.colorAccent, 60, "Internet"));

    LineChart2 lineChart2 = new LineChart2(this, items);

    anyDesiredLayout.addView(lineChart2);
```

**EDIT**

The issue is that you're creating two views

This line `new LineChart2(this, items);`  will create new view which is different than the view that you have attached in your xml.

In `lineChart2` case you can see that `items` has been set correctly in `lineChart2` constructor. But `onDraw` hasn't been invoked because you didn't attach the view to any container.

And the view in your xml `onDraw` method will be invoked but you will find `items` list is null. Because `LineChart2(Context context, List<items> items)` has never been invoked.

Comment: It makes no sense to me. I have List<items> items initialised. The List gets past through the constructor. If I want to get the size in the constructor it returns 3, correct. If I do this on every other method its 0 or it gives me a null pointer exception

Comment: Please check the edited answer i have explained it further.

Comment: @JonnyDough I hope my answer helped you. if it fixes your question please mark it as the answer. :)